Не билдятся сборки с локализоваными ресурсами
Почему-то перестала работать следующая,простая схема локализации WPF приложения, когда в приложении, например, есть файл Strings.resx, в котором находятся пары ключ-значение со значениями на английском, а таке же файл Strings.ru.resx, без класса, а котором находятся те же ключи, но со значениями на русском языке, и при компиляции в папке с dll при билде автоматически создается папка ru с такой же сборкой, но в которой есть только ресурсы Strings с русскими значениями. Не могу понять почему при компиляция Студия не создает эту вложеную папку с dll, пишет следующее: MSB3030  не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0\ru\Telesyk.WPF.Localization.resources.dll" - файл не найден.  Localization    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets  4958
Кто сталкивался с таким?
